# Use Android DataBinding plugin parallel to GoogleServices plugin

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin, google-app-invites, android-databinding

was anyone able to use Android DataBinding plugin parallel to GoogleServices pluginplugin?

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'
    classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'
```

And then the whole project just exploded. When I remove services plugin then databinding works.

This is gradle's stacktrace.

```
[data binding plugin]: failed to setup data binding
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.getApplicationVariants()Lorg/gradle/api/internal/DefaultDomainObjectSet;
    at android.databinding.tool.DataBinderPlugin.createXmlProcessorForApp(DataBinderPlugin.java:233)
    at android.databinding.tool.DataBinderPlugin.createXmlProcessor(DataBinderPlugin.java:200)
    at android.databinding.tool.DataBinderPlugin.access$200(DataBinderPlugin.java:65)
    at android.databinding.tool.DataBinderPlugin$1.execute(DataBinderPlugin.java:156)
    at android.databinding.tool.DataBinderPlugin$1.execute(DataBinderPlugin.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:113)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:488)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:86)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:82)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:75)
    at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.select(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$5.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:162)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runBuildOperation(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:189)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:159)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:104)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runRootBuildOperation(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:184)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I'm having similar issues with Databinding and anything with a `1.4.0-beta3` attached to it. I've just been using `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'` instead.

Comment: Yep, just ran into the exact same problem myself. Updating to 1.4.0-beta3 made the project explode, so basically had to downgrade again (though I just went to 1.3.0 - not the beta). Seems like a bug that needs reporting to Google.

Answer (score 3):

No need to downgrade. There is/was a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188041) in some versions of the gradle plugin. To make things better, the [Data Binding](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) docs are a little out of date. Ignore the parts about how to get it set up. Try this instead:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0-beta1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

On a new project, I had databinding working perfectly, even without the declare it enabled.

But after add new GoogleServices support, I had exactly the same error.

Add:

```
android {
. . .

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Fixed.

My Project gradle file (hope help someone):

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha7'
    classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1"
    classpath 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha5'
```

. . .